# dropdownlistfor in for loop, how to have different select ids? In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 5 dropdownlist in my view with the same data, I only want to change Selected and the select ids in the select!

How to make that in the view and in the controller?
This line need to be changed

```
viewModel.TestSelectList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text",r.Next(1, 3));
```

Im using mvc5

View

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.TestId, Model.TestSelectList)
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
 var viewModel = new TestView();
 List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() {
  new SelectListItem(){ Selected = false,Value="1", Text="ActionScript"},
  new SelectListItem(){ Selected = false,Value="2", Text="AppleScript"},
  new SelectListItem(){ Selected = true, Value="3", Text="Asp"},
        };
 Random r = new Random();
 viewModel.TestSelectList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text",r.Next(1, 3));
}

public class TestView
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public SelectList TestSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

**View**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
     var generateRandomId = "testId" + i;
     @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.TestId, Model.TestSelectList, new { @id = generateRandomId})
}
```

Comment: Works well on the View

But how do I do the Controller
viewModel.TestSelectList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text",r.Next(1, 3));?